# Wordpress shows forbidden from another server

Tags: wordpress, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have a wordpress installation on an IIS7 Windows Server 2008 shared hosting service.

It didn't have any problems till few days ago.

Now, when I edit a post or submit a comment while I'm logged in, this page appears:
[image]

for example, if I send a comment while I'm logged in as an admin on my site, comment will send, but I see that page instead of comment sent page...

As you see, it shows an ((Apache CentOS , nginx)) server, but my server is a windows (IIS) server!!

is my site hacked? or ...? What's going wrong with my website?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was from `PubSubHubbub` plugin. (I think from invalid sites on its settings)

I deactivated it and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, Wordpress runs best on Apache, with PHP5 & MySQL. I can't see the error in your screenshot very well, but it could be due because you tried to use the non-default permalink structure on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from the screenshot it looks like you may have a bad update service listed which is messing with IIS.  You can the update services that you are currently sending to under Settings > Writing in your admin area.  You should try temporarily removing all of the update services and see if that resolves the issue.

Here's a more through explanation:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Update_Services